# How can I test to make sure an application that use github's api works correctly for private repos?

Tags: github-api

I don't have any private github repositories, but I want to create an application that works for people who do. How can I test to ensure my app will work for private repos without paying for one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you ask someone who does have a private repo to test it out? You'll need a real user with real private repositories, there's no "testing mode" in the API which would allow you to test if you app works.

Comment: I mean I'll have to if there's no other way, but it doesn't bode well for ensuring my integration continues to work. Its kind of lame to not have a development mode, when every single usage of an API needs to be developed and tested. I see you work at github, is "there is no way" for sure the answer?

Comment: As I mentioned above -- no, the GitHub API doesn't offer such a "development mode" currently. I do agree it would be useful, but I don't expect that to happen anytime soon.